# Count records and return zero where non exist

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to sum an amount from a table. Where no records exist my function must return zero, but it doesn't. I get '#Error'. Here is my function:

```
Public Function Fees() As Double

Fees = Nz(DSum("MyFee", "tblDisclosure", "Volunteer = True And Not IsNull(ReceiptsLookup) and RequestDate> DateSerial(Year (Date),Month (Date),1)-1"), 0)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with a proper criteria string:

```
Public Function Fees() As Double

    Fees = Nz(DSum("MyFee", "tblDisclosure", "Volunteer = True And Not IsNull(ReceiptsLookup) And RequestDate > DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 0)"), 0)

End Function
```